# UID from AD servers using " idmap config ad " for multiple domains

Tags: linux, active-directory, amazon-web-services, samba

This is my current setup: we have 2 domains named as TEST1 and TEST2.

TEST1 domain is the default domain to which successfully integrated my linux Clients.

But users and group credentials have to be received from another trusted domain named TEST2.

The UID (uidNumber) and GID have to be fetched from TEST2 AD server. Below is the `smb.conf` file content.

```
[global]
       workgroup = TEST1
       realm = TEST1.LOCAL
       netbios name = LIN01
       security = ads
       winbind offline logon = no
       allow trusted domains = yes
       winbind enum users = no
       winbind enum groups = no
       winbind use default domain = yes
       template home dir = /home/%U
       template shell = /bin/bash

       idmap config * : backend = tdb
       idmap config * : range = 2000000-2999999

       idmap config TEST2 : backend = ad
       idmap config TEST2 : schema_mode = rfc2307
       idmap config TEST2 : range = 1000-1999999

       winbind nss info = rfc2307


# wbinfo -i TEST2\\user2
failed to call wbcGetpwnam: WBC_ERR_DOMAIN_NOT_FOUND
Could not get info for user TEST2\user2

# wbinfo -i TEST1\\user1
user1:*:2000000:2000004:user1:/home/user1:/bin/bash
```